# /media directory not working anymore

Tags: linux, ubuntu-16.04, usb-drive

I can't automount USB sticks on my linux because I have several problems with `/media` directory. 
Here is my `ls -al` result on `/` (I just kept the `media` and `mnt` directories for you) :

```
total 116
drwxr-xr-x  25 root       root        4096 juin  13 09:39 .
drwxr-xr-x  25 root       root        4096 juin  13 09:39 ..
drwx------   8 acarbonaro acarbonaro  8192 janv.  1  1970 media
drwxr-xr-x   2 root       root        4096 avril 11  2014 mnt
```

This already seems strange as for other users it is often owned by root.

When I try to `sudo chown root:root media` it says `permission denied`.

When I try to `sudo chown 755 media` it doesn't say anything but when I `ls -l` after nothing has changed.

The other problem : I don't know why but the media directory is empty I can't find the user directory that used to be in it.

When I plug a USB flash drive, it cannot auto mount. I have to mount it manually in another directory, which is not impossible but clearly not handy.

Thank you for your help.

**EDIT**:

Here is my `df -T` result :

```
Sys. de fichiers Type     blocs de 1K  Utilisé Disponible Uti% Monté sur
udev             devtmpfs     4015584        8    4015576   1% /dev
tmpfs            tmpfs         805680     1212     804468   1% /run
/dev/sda1        ext4       115214888  9815468   99523708   9% /
none             tmpfs              4        0          4   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
none             tmpfs           5120        0       5120   0% /run/lock
none             tmpfs        4028392   522580    3505812  13% /run/shm
none             tmpfs         102400      600     101800   1% /run/user
/dev/sda2        ext4       130654772 18532260  105462572  15% /home
/dev/sdb2        vfat        14938864   218480   14720384   2% /media
```

**EDIT**:

I don't know the answer to my problem, but rebooting reset the `/media` directory as it was before and it works agian.

Comment: Can you provide output of `df -T`? Does rebooting help by chance?

Comment: I edited my post. Thanks for your help. I will reboot and tell you if it helps

Comment: Rebooting helped. It works again. Thank you.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: I didn't know that these websites were linked. Now I do. Sorry for the misunderstanding

Answer (score -1):

I assume the problem was that you have yanked the USB stick out of port without unmounting. UNIX is not very keen to parts of its FS disappearing. Next time, `umount` it first, then remove.